# how to sum values at the same time getting all rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sum

İ have a video table named videos and here these are the columns :

```
vid    v_uid    v_view   v_title   v_info
1       45      56487     foo       foo
2       45      455
3       45      98989
...
```

My condition will be " where v_uid = 45 " and i want to get rows belongs to this id "45" and sum this users video views as total views.

thanks.

Comment: show the table result who you wants.

Comment: try the answer given by Paul Dixon it will surely help you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I read the question as you want to get all rows *and* a sum of those rows in one query.

You could do this all in one hit using [WITH ROLLUP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html), e.g.

```
select *,sum(v_view) as total from videos 
where v_uid=45 
group by vid with rollup;
```

Bit hacky, as we don't really need the group by (which is why I'm grouping on the row id vid). What you'll end up with all the individual rows, and a final row with the total sum in it (it will have a NULL vid too, which might help identify it)

If you just want a sum of the views, then you can execute something much simpler

```
select sum(v_view) as total from videos where v_uid=45;
```

Comment: thanks for sharing knowledge i came to know a new thing that if we want multiple recoreds using group by then i should group by them with primary key yupp thats pretty good approach